# Known bounds on $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)-f(x-a)|dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Suppose that $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$. Are there any know result for estimating the quantity
$$
I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(x)-f(x-a)|dx.
$$

I have the following results: (i) If $f$ is strictly increasing (equivalently $f(-x)$ strictly decreasing),
$$
\begin{align}
I(a)&=\int_{f(\mathbb{R})} \left[f^{-1}(y)+a-f^{-1}(y)\right]dy \\
&\leq\int_{[-M,M]} a\,dy \\
&= 2Ma
\end{align}
$$

(ii) If $f\geq0$, $f$ strictly increasing on $(-\infty,0)$ and strictly decreasing on $(0,\infty)$. By the intermediate value theorem, there exist $c\in(0,a)$ such that $f(c)=f(c-a)$, then
$$
\begin{align}
I(a)&=\int_{-\infty}^c \left[f(x)-f(x-a)\right]dx+\int_c^\infty\left[f(x-a)-f(x)\right]dx \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^cf(x)dx-\int_{-\infty}^{c-a}f(x)dx+\int_{c-a}^\infty f(x)dx-\int_c^\infty f(x)dx \\
&=2\int_{c-a}^c f(x)dx \\
&\leq 2Ma
\end{align} 
$$

Is there a generalization of such bound? My guess would be that for any bounded continuous function that has finitely many extrema,
$$
I(a)\leq 2aMn,
$$
where $n$ is the number of extrema. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The integral is the area between the graphs of $f(x)$ and $f(x-a)$. Your bound looks very plausible. I think the idea is to look at the intersection of the region with horizontal lines, showing that each such intersection has length bounded by a constant involving $a$.

Comment: $I(a)\ne\int_{\Bbb R}$ since $f=\sin$ causes divergence

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I stated that $f$ needs to have finitely many extrema. The function $\sin(x)$ does not apply.

Comment: I meant that the first equation in your post isn't well-defined for every allowed $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note the integral does converge if $f$ has a finite number of local maxima. Indeed, in this case the function is eventually monotone and bounded, thus the integral telescopes, thus is finite.

**Hint for a less sharp estimate:**

1. Let $f$ be an increasing(or decreasing) function on $(-\infty, r]$(or $[r, \infty)$).  Prove that  $I_\tilde{f}(a)\le 3M a$ for $\tilde{f}= f \chi_{[-\infty,r]}.$
2. Let $f$ be an increasing function on $[r_1,r_2],$ Let $\tilde{f}= f \chi_{[r_1,r_2]},$ prove that $I_\tilde{f}(a)\le 4M a.$
3. Now for a function $f$ that has finite local maxima, let $\{-\infty =r_0 <r_1< ...<r_{n-1}< r_n= \infty\}$ be the set points at which $f$ attain its local maxima. Write $$f_i= f \chi_{[r_i,r_{i+1}]},$$ then by the triangle inequality $$I_f(a) \le \sum_{i=0}^n I_{f_i}(a).$$
4. Use the estimates in (1) and (2).

Note that if you manage to get better bounds for (1) and (2), you can get a better bound in (3). I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this! I am formulating a similar proof using the triangle inequality but with functions with one peak, which is more difficult than necessary. Also, a sharper bound can be obtained by considering only positive function, since $I_{f}(a)=I_{f+M}(a)$.

Comment: But isn't $f+M$ no longer bounded by the same bound as $f$? I don't see where you would you use the positivity of $f,$ I don't see where you used it in (ii) as well. Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: Sorry, you are right.